# Getting many shipping addresses for one order number

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using 4 tables

- CUSTOMER
- CUSTOMER_ORDER
- CUST_ORDER_LINE
- CUST_ADDRESS

I used Inner joins to link the tables. `CUSTOMER` is linked to `CUSTOMER_ORDER` and `CUST_ADDRESS` by customer_ID, and `CUSTOMER_ORDER_LINE` is linked to `CUSTOMER_ORDER` by order_ID. Order_ID does not appear in the `CUSTOMER` or `CUST_ADDRESS` tables.

When I run the query below, I get every shipping address on record for that particular customer and order number.

For example, a distributor has 25 possible shipping addresses, but they only ship one order to one shipping address at a time. My query is bringing back one order number 25 times for every address. Any advice would be wonderful. Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME, 
    dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID, 
    dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIPTO_ID, 
    dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME AS Expr1
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMER.ID = dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID = dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.CUST_ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CUST_ADDRESS 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMER.ID = dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE     (dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ORDER_DATE > '1/1/2014') 
    AND (dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID NOT LIKE 'RMA%')
GROUP BY dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER.NAME, 
    dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.PART_ID, 
    dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE.ORDER_QTY, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.STATUS, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIPTO_ID, 
    dbo.CUST_ADDRESS.NAME
ORDER BY dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER.ID
```

Comment: If a customer has 25 addresses to ship to, how would I know which address a certain order is supposed to go to?

Comment: Each address has a shipto_ID and each distributor has a customer number. The combination of the two are unique. Sometimes the order is shipped directly to the distributor otherwise it is drop shipped to the final customer. Our master level distributors may have upwards of 1,000 addresses. In our ERP software, the bill to and ship to addresses are on the order entry screen and linked to an order number.

Comment: So can you just join the addresses table based on the order shipto_id field?  Also, why are you doing a group by?  There doesn't seem to be a need for that (or I'm just missing something).

Comment: I cannot join that way because the address table does not contain shipto_ID, but the order table does. The address table is joined to the customer table by customer_ID, and the customer_order table is also linked by customer_ID. The CUST_ORDER_LINE tables has all the sales data I want, but it doesn't have any common fields to the address or customer tables. The order_line tables is linked to the customer_order table by sales order_ID. I can get customer shipping info or customer order info, but not both together. I'm just learning how to write queries, the Group By may not be needed.

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere, but I'm still a little lost.  Why can you get either the customer shipping info or the order info, but not both?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I can get both, but the rows are not linked together. For example, say there is an order number with two part numbers on it, being billed to a distributors address, and being shipped to a final customer. I can get an order number repeated twice for the two part numbers(thats good), the two part numbers, their quantities, billing customer name, and shipto_ID. Now, when I add physical shipping columns from the shipping address table, I get all the addresses under that distributor name. I only want one unique shipping address for that one order.

Comment: In the example above, the database returns 2 lines for the one order number, but returns about 2,000 when adding shipping state, city, or address.

Comment: That's because your join is from Customer to Customer_Address. You need to change that join predicate to join on CUSTOMER_ORDER.SHIPTO_ID = CUST_ADDRESS.CUSTOMER_ID. Also, you really should use aliases in your sql. It will make things a lot easier to read.

Comment: Why do you have distinct top (100) percent in this query? top (100) percent is pointless. Also you have both distinct and a group by, they are both doing the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Can I join two different fields? Shipto_ID is just a number, while Customer_ID is a customer account number with letters included. I believe that you are correct, I don't have my joins set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As a shot in the dark it seems your query should be something like this.

```
SELECT 
    co.ID, 
    c.NAME, 
    col.PART_ID, 
    col.ORDER_QTY, 
    co.STATUS, 
    co.SHIPTO_ID, 
    ca.NAME AS Expr1
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER c
    INNER JOIN  dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER co ON c.ID = co.CUSTOMER_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE col ON co.ID = col.CUST_ORDER_ID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CUST_ADDRESS ca ON co.SHIPTO_ID = ca.CUSTOMER_ID --this is now joining to the order table.
WHERE co.ORDER_DATE > '2014-01-01'
    AND co.ID NOT LIKE 'RMA%'
GROUP BY co.ID, 
    c.NAME, 
    col.PART_ID, 
    col.ORDER_QTY, 
    co.STATUS, 
    co.SHIPTO_ID, 
    ca.NAME
ORDER BY co.ID
```

Notice how using aliases makes this look a lot cleaner. I also changed up the string date to use the generally accepted format. This will work regardless of your DATEFORMAT setting.

Comment: I duplicated the query above, but it would not execute. No error messages appeared, but no data came back. The aliases really helped btw.

Comment: I can't see your data so I can't help a lot here but maybe change the inner join to CUST_ADDRESS to a left join?

Comment: Does it make sense that the problem has to do with the CUST_ORDER_LINE table and CUST_ADDRESS table having no common fields between the two? The cust_order_line table is only linked to the customer_order table by order#, which isn't in the other tables. Would it be possible for me to send you a screen shot of the diagram in the design pane? Would this help?

Comment: Well somewhere in your Order (or coulr be OrderLine) you have to know which address you want to ship the order to. A screenshot might get it there. Try that and we will see what we can find out.

Comment: I can't post a screenshot because my reputation isn't high enough unfortunately.

Comment: Then go to sqlfiddle.com and create a fiddle with the three tables. There has to be something that ties an order to the selected shipping address. That is what you want to join on.